# Remove animation of search icon in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Is there anyway to remove the animation of UISearchBar search icon, which animates from center to left of UISearchBar when responded?

The search icon should appear on left instead of center of UISearchBar and it should not animates when responded by user.

Comment: You might want to post more detail re: how you're instantiating it, the code you're using to instantiate it, delegate methods you've implemented, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc public class LeftAlignedSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {
    override public var placeholder:String? {
        didSet {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                if let text = placeholder {
                    if text.characters.last! != " " {
                        let attr = UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([LeftAlignedSearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes
                        let maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 86, 40)
                        let widthText = text.boundingRectWithSize( maxSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:attr, context:nil).size.width
                        let widthSpace = " ".boundingRectWithSize( maxSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:attr, context:nil).size.width
                        let spaces = floor((maxSize.width - widthText) / widthSpace)
                        let newText = text + ((Array(count: Int(spaces), repeatedValue: " ").joinWithSeparator("")))
                        if newText != text {
                            placeholder = newText
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-left-aligned-uisearchbar-b51ef36b6e1b

Answer (score 0):

Going off of **Krennex's** answer I converted it to **Swift 3**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LeftAlignedSearchBar: UISearchBar, UISearchBarDelegate {



    override var placeholder:String? {
        didSet {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                if let text = placeholder {
                    if text.characters.last! != " " {

                        let textField = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [LeftAlignedSearchBar.self])

                        let maxSize = CGSize(width: self.bounds.size.width - 100, height: 40)

                        let widthText = text.boundingRect( with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:textField.defaultTextAttributes, context:nil).size.width

                        let widthSpace = " ".boundingRect( with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes:textField.defaultTextAttributes, context:nil).size.width

                        let spaces = floor((maxSize.width - widthText) / widthSpace)

                        let newText = text + ((Array(repeating: " ", count: Int(spaces)).joined(separator: "")))

                        if newText != text {
                            placeholder = "\(newText)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer **Krennex**!